# How to sort posts in admin by titles with dd.mm.yyyy format?

Tags: wp-query, sort, pre-get-posts

I have created a Custom Post Type for Booking, new posts are inserted by visitors and the title is formatted as date on which the booking takes place. So, the post list in admin looks like this:

[image]

Is there a way I could order those posts in admin list by those date titles?
Generally solution would be I guess to get the titles, transform them to dates and then sort those posts. If so, how can I do it inside pre_get_posts() filter?

Maybe I could have done this better, but everything else about these functionality works great. Each post contains ACF repeater with time in steps so it is a little bit more complicated inside.

EDIT:

This is how I have filter, it correctly modifies `posts_per_page` just to make sure it works. I have tried recreating it as a plugin class.

```
public function __construct(){
    add_action( 'pre_get_posts', array($this, 'sort_admin_daily_reservations'));
    add_filter( 'posts_orderby', array($this, 'test_sorting_filter' ), 10, 2);
}


public function sort_admin_daily_reservations($query) {

    if(is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && in_array ($query->get('post_type'), array('Booking')) )
    {
        $query->set('orderby', 'wpse_mod_title');
        $query->set('order', 'DESC');   
        //$query->set('posts_per_page', 2);
    }
    return $query;

}


public function test_sorting_filter($orderby, \WP_Query $q) {

    global $wpdb;

    $_orderby = $q->get( 'orderby' );
    $_order   = $q->get( 'order' );

    if('wpse_mod_title ' === $_orderby && in_array( $_order , [ 'ASC', 'DESC' ], true ))
        $orderby = " CONCAT(
            SUBSTRING( {$wpdb->posts}.post_title, 7, 4 ), 
            SUBSTRING( {$wpdb->posts}.post_title, 4, 2 ), 
            SUBSTRING( {$wpdb->posts}.post_title, 1, 2 ) 
        ) {$_order} ";

    return $orderby;

}
```

Comment: Are those dates string? If so, you can't sort it by date. `02.12.2099` comes before `20.01.1990`, and after `01.11.1980`. But if this is the real post's date, then you can sort them by date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the post titles have the date format `DD.MM.YYYY.`

We can order the `DD.MM.YYYY` titles as `YYYYMMDD` with:

```
$query = new WP_Query( [ 'orderby' => 'wpse_mod_title ' ] );
```

that's supported with this kind of plugin:

```
/**
 * Plugin Name: WPSE-274981: Sort DD.MM.YYYY Post Titles as YYYYMMDD In WP_Query 
 * Desription:  Supported by the wpse_mod_title orderby value
 */
add_filter( 'posts_orderby', function( $orderby, \WP_Query $q ) use ( &$wpdb )
{
    $_orderby = $q->get( 'orderby' );
    $_order   = $q->get( 'order' );

    if( 'wpse_mod_title' === $_orderby && in_array( $_order , [ 'ASC', 'DESC' ], true ) )
        $orderby = " CONCAT(
            SUBSTRING( {$wpdb->posts}.post_title, 7, 4 ), // Get the YYYY part
            SUBSTRING( {$wpdb->posts}.post_title, 4, 2 ), // Get the MM part
            SUBSTRING( {$wpdb->posts}.post_title, 1, 2 )  // Get the DD part
        ) {$_order} ";

    return $orderby; 
}, 10, 2 );
```

Note that this assumes the strict `DD.MM.YYYY` title format, without spaces.

We might consider trimming it in SQL to make it more flexible.

*I think I'm under the influence of @bonger or @thedeadmedic to write this kind of substring ordering.* ;-)

But consider another approaches first, like writing the titles in a sortable way, in the first place.

Comment: Hmm I don't seem to understand what does this code do :) by the way, could you please look at my comment on the question?

Comment: CurrentIy the title looks like dd.mm.yyyy.,  that's not easy to date sort, but if we reverse it to .yyyy.mm.dd in the SQL query, then it's easier to sort. (skipping date conversions here) @JackJohansson

Comment: Yes I thought about that for a moment, but then I wondered if the post titles are actual date of publish, which some of them might belong to the years before 2000.

Comment: if the date titles are the same as publish date, then OP should sort by post_date instead, but I assumed that was not the case ;-) @JackJohansson

Comment: No no, I mean the actual publish date for the book, like _The Lord of the Rings_, 1000 years B.C ( 1955 actually ) :)

Comment: hehe, you mean before 0000:00:00, I guess one could consider prefixing or postfixing the titles to fix the ordering or mark them in other ways ;-)

Comment: :D Prefix can actually work. Otherwise, we see Tolkien's book before Harry Potter :)

Comment: I updated the answer, as I wasn't thinking clearly regarding reversing the titles ;-)

Comment: Happens to me too :) sorry it was the first time I had a doubt about one of your posts :)

Comment: Thank you for providing solution, I can't get it to work, nothing changes. If I use your code I get an error, but it is ok if I place $ character here - "use ( &$wpdb )". Am I calling these filter wrong?

Comment: Yes that, was a typo, missing $ (mine is untested). Might use global $wpdb instead, it's currently missing in your method.  Hope you can double check the substring indices. You're calling non-existent test_sorting_filter() method.  @IvanTopić

Comment: I think the position of SUBSTRING starts with 1, not 0 ? @IvanTopić

Comment: You are right, I have played with various parameters. PHP substr starts from 0, MySQL substring starts from 1. But I am so stupid, you have an empty space after 'wpse_mod_title ' in IF clause so that is why the code didn't evaluated :D OMG Anyway, thank you very much, it works great now :)

Comment: glad to hear it worked for you, sorry about the extra space ;-) @IvanTopić